# T-SQL Inserting into table from stored procedure SLOW

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a very complicated stored procedure that we use to capture and manipulate sales figures. It runs (typically) in less than a second in SQL Server.

I want to use the raw output as a basis for another stored procedure that manipulates the data further for a specific business purpose.

At the moment I am simply defining my `@results` table variable, and doing the following:

```
@Results1 TABLE 
    (
        HeadId INT,
        AreaId INT,
        BranchId INT,
        SiteId INT,
        Description VARCHAR(50),
        EWC VARCHAR(8),
        S_Volume NUMERIC(10,6),
        S_Weight NUMERIC(10,6),
        S_Volume_Recycle NUMERIC(10,6),
        S_Weight_Recycle NUMERIC(10,6),
        M_Volume NUMERIC(10,6),
        M_Weight NUMERIC(10,6),
        M_Volume_Recycle NUMERIC(10,6),
        M_Weight_Recycle NUMERIC(10,6), 
        T_Volume NUMERIC(10,6),
        T_Weight NUMERIC(10,6),
        T_Volume_Recycle NUMERIC(10,6),
        T_Weight_Recycle NUMERIC(10,6)
    )

INSERT INTO @Results1
    EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_MasterDataExtractVolumes] 
         N'01/01/2018',
         N'01/01/2019',
         1604,
         NULL, NULL, NULL

SELECT * 
FROM @results1
```

The stored procedure takes over 10 seconds to run (10 x slower).

I have tried using `#results1` and also using

```
INSERT INTO @Results1
    EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_MasterDataExtractVolumes] 
         N'01/01/2018',
         N'01/01/2019',
         1604,
         NULL, NULL, NULL
```

I've tried using `OPENQUERY` with no performance advantage.

Comment: The root cause is probably parameter sniffing. [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Check what it's waiting on for that 10 seconds (see sys.dm_exec_requests for example).

Comment: I did some more tests today and If I don't do the INSERT it runs just fine.

Comment: I have also done some hunting around and found two indexes that were created to 'improve' reporting speed.
I disabled them and now the Stored Procedure in SSMS runs at approximately 6 seconds and so does the nested version.

So in this particular case It would seem that an index was causing an issue.